# Intel De1-SoC VGA controller in VHDL

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl, intel-fpga, vga

I have implemented a VGA controller in VHDL using the timing specifications for a 600x480 monitor as described in the attached photos.  The module takes in a 50MHz clock and is supposed to draw a square on the upper left hand corner of the screen as output.  When I run the software (.sof file) on an Intel De1-SoC FPGA board I only get a black screen.  The board is communicating with the monitor as the splash screen on start does display correctly.  Is there something wrong with my attached code? The screen flashes and then displays nothing for me.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity VGA is 
  port(
      CLK, RST: in STD_LOGIC;
      HSYNC, VSYNC: out STD_LOGIC;
      R, G, B: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0) --8 pins for RGB
      );
end entity VGA;

architecture Behavioral of VGA is

    signal clk25 : std_logic := '0';
    
    constant HD : integer := 639;  --  639   Horizontal Display (640)
    constant HFP : integer := 16;         --   16   Right border (front porch)
    constant HSP : integer := 96;       --   96   Sync pulse (Retrace)
    constant HBP : integer := 48;        --   48   Left boarder (back porch)
    
    constant VD : integer := 479;   --  479   Vertical Display (480)
    constant VFP : integer := 10;            --   10   Right border (front porch)
    constant VSP : integer := 2;                 --    2   Sync pulse (Retrace)
    constant VBP : integer := 33;       --   33   Left boarder (back porch)
    
    signal hPos : integer := 0;
    signal vPos : integer := 0;
    
    signal videoOn : std_logic := '0';

begin


clk_div:process(CLK)
begin
    if(CLK'event and CLK = '1')then
        clk25 <= not clk25;
    end if;
end process;

Horizontal_position_counter:process(clk25, RST)
begin
    if(RST = '0')then
        hpos <= 0;
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 = '1')then
        if (hPos = (HD + HFP + HSP + HBP)) then
            hPos <= 0;
        else
            hPos <= hPos + 1;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

Vertical_position_counter:process(clk25, RST, hPos)
begin
    if(RST = '0')then
        vPos <= 0;
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 = '1')then
        if(hPos = (HD + HFP + HSP + HBP))then
            if (vPos = (VD + VFP + VSP + VBP)) then
                vPos <= 0;
            else
                vPos <= vPos + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

Horizontal_Synchronisation:process(clk25, RST, hPos)
begin
    if(RST = '0')then
        HSYNC <= '0';
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 = '1')then
        if((hPos <= (HD + HFP)) OR (hPos > HD + HFP + HSP))then
            HSYNC <= '1';
        else
            HSYNC <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

Vertical_Synchronisation:process(clk25, RST, vPos)
begin
    if(RST = '0')then
        VSYNC <= '0';
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 = '1')then
        if((vPos <= (VD + VFP)) OR (vPos > VD + VFP + VSP))then
            VSYNC <= '1';
        else
            VSYNC <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

video_on:process(clk25, RST, hPos, vPos)
begin
    if(RST = '0')then
        videoOn <= '0';
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 = '1')then
        if(hPos <= HD and vPos <= VD)then
            videoOn <= '1';
        else
            videoOn <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
end process;


draw:process(clk25, RST, hPos, vPos, videoOn)
begin
    if(RST = '0')then
        R <= (others => '0');
        G <= (others => '0');
        B <= (others => '0');
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 = '1')then
        if(videoOn = '1')then
            if((hPos >= 10 and hPos <= 60) AND (vPos >= 10 and vPos <= 60))then
                R <= (others => '1');
                G <= (others => '1');
                B <= (others => '1');
            else
                R <= (others => '0');
                G <= (others => '0');
                B <= (others => '0');
            end if;
        else
            R <= (others => '0');
            G <= (others => '0');
            B <= (others => '0');
        end if;
    end if;
end process;


end Behavioral;
```

[image: 640x480 VGA Timing Map]

[image: Timing Specifications]
[image: Splash Screen]

[image: Hsync=0]
[image: Hsync=1]
[image: Vsync=0]
[image: Vsync=1]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: Horizontal Timing]

[image: Vertical Timing]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116278/discussion-on-question-by-sweet-nemesis-intel-de1-soc-vga-controller-in-vhdl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working VGA code that will display a white screen.  You needed to delay HSYNC and VSYNC by one clock cycle to account for a one clock delay between the video on (data enable) and the pixel RGB data.  I changed the `video on` signal to a `data enable` signal since this is standard convention for LCD panels.  The `data enable` signal goes high whenever pixel data is active.  Be sure to route the 25 MHz pixel clock `VCLK` to VGA_CLK, PIN_A11, of your development board.  The ADV7123 chip is a video DAC that needs the 25 MHz pixel clock to operate.  You also need a blanking signal (VGA_BLANK_N, PIN_F10) and a sync signal (VGA_SYNC_N, PIN_C10) according to the ADV7123 datasheet.  The blanking signal is generated by the `data enable` signal and is active low.  When `data enable` is low, `blank` is asserted.  The `sync` signal is unused so drive the pin low.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity VGA is
  port(
      CLK, RST: in STD_LOGIC;
      VCLK, HSYNC, VSYNC, BLANK, SYNC: out STD_LOGIC;
      R, G, B: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0) --8 pins for RGB
      );
end entity VGA;

architecture rtl of VGA is

    constant HD  : integer   := 640; --  640   Horizontal Display (640)
    constant HFP : integer   := 16;  --   16   Right border (front porch)
    constant HSP : integer   := 96;  --   96   Sync pulse (Retrace)
    constant HBP : integer   := 48;  --   48   Left boarder (back porch)

    constant VD  : integer   := 480; --  480   Vertical Display (480)
    constant VFP : integer   := 10;  --   10   Right border (front porch)
    constant VSP : integer   := 2;   --    2   Sync pulse (Retrace)
    constant VBP : integer   := 33;  --   33   Left boarder (back porch)

    signal clk25 : std_logic := '0';

    signal hPos  : integer   := 0;
    signal vPos  : integer   := 0;

    signal hs    : std_logic := '0'; -- register to account for pixel data delay
    signal vs    : std_logic := '0'; -- register to account for pixel data delay
    signal de    : std_logic := '0';

begin

-- outputs
SYNC <= '0';
VCLK <= clk25;

clk_div:process(CLK)
begin
    if(CLK'event and CLK = '1')then
        clk25 <= not clk25;
    end if;
end process;

Horizontal_position_counter:process(clk25, RST)
begin
    if(RST = '0')then
        hpos <= 0;
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 = '1')then
        if (hPos = (HD + HFP + HSP + HBP - 1)) then
            hPos <= 0;
        else
            hPos <= hPos + 1;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

Vertical_position_counter:process(clk25, RST)
begin
    if(RST = '0')then
        vPos <= 0;
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 = '1')then
        if(hPos = (HD + HFP + HSP + HBP - 1)) then
            if (vPos = (VD + VFP + VSP + VBP - 1)) then
                vPos <= 0;
            else
                vPos <= vPos + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

Horizontal_Synchronisation:process(clk25, RST)
begin
    if(RST = '0')then
        hs    <= '0';
        HSYNC <= '0';
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 = '1')then
        if((hPos >= (HD + HFP)) AND (hPos < HD + HFP + HSP))then
            hs <= '0';
        else
            hs <= '1';
        end if;
        HSYNC <= hs; -- delay one clock to account for pixel data delay
    end if;
end process;

Vertical_Synchronisation:process(clk25, RST)
begin
    if(RST = '0')then
        vs    <= '0';
        VSYNC <= '0';
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 = '1')then
        if((vPos >= (VD + VFP)) AND (vPos < VD + VFP + VSP))then
            vs <= '0';
        else
            vs <= '1';
        end if;
        VSYNC <= vs; -- delay one clock to account for pixel data delay
    end if;
end process;

video_on:process(clk25, RST)
begin
    if(RST = '0')then
        de    <= '0';
        BLANK <= '0';
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 = '1')then
        if(hPos < HD and vPos < VD)then
            de <= '1';
        else
            de <= '0';
        end if;
        BLANK <= de; -- delay one clock to align with pixel data
    end if;
end process;

draw:process(clk25, RST)
begin
    if(RST = '0')then
        R <= (others => '0');
        G <= (others => '0');
        B <= (others => '0');
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 = '1')then
        if(de = '1')then
          R <= (others => '1');
          G <= (others => '1');
          B <= (others => '1');
        else
          R <= (others => '0');
          G <= (others => '0');
          B <= (others => '0');
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

end;
```

Comment: I just tried to run this on the board and I still get a blank screen.  Maybe I'm still missing something with the hardware?

Comment: Can you try again, I made some updates to the code.  Blank is active low, I originally had it active high.  Also, what kind of monitor are you driving?

Comment: Just one more tiny note, I changed the `sync` signal to logic low.  Since sync information isn't required on the green channel, the datasheet recommends to drive `sync` low.

Comment: "replace your code with mine" is not an answer.  An *answer* would explain the issue, but that is impossible as the question is missing key pieces.  EESE is not a code writing service.

Comment: I described the issues with the code in the explanation above the code.  And described how to fix it.  There were some signals missing from the ADV7123 interface.  IMO he described the issue well, demonstrated that he at least tried to get the design working, and posted enough detailed information for someone to help.

Comment: I didn't think to look at the DAC datasheet and only looked at the board's documentation.  Hard lesson learned. Again, thank you so much!  You really saved the day! :-)